# MEAN Stack socket.io pushing to client when existing data gets updated

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, sockets, mean-stack

I am working on a MEAN & Socket.io project where Mongodb in the back-end holds my data and I am using socket.io to publish newly arrived data to all the clients. To make it real time, I am using Mongodb capped collection to send newly arrived data (Insert) to all the clients using socket.io emit. But, I am struggling to find a way to send updated data to a client when existing data gets updated.

I know an alternative way but for that I have to move my data from MongoDB to a flat file and create a watch for that file. But, its not an elegant solution.

If anyone have any better suggestion please share.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why can't use something like this on the server side 
whenever there is an update that needs the view to be updated in the frontend

```
socket.emit('updateData1', {_id: <_id of the data you are updating>, field1: <value>, field2:<value>})
```

In the front-end(client) just look up the `_id` and update the object.